# Why Firebase Doesnt Follow a Proper Pattern when importing a JSON?

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am importing a JSON where I Nicely Sorted out all Keys in a Structured Manner as you can see in the Screenshot :
[image]

This is after I convert the CSV data into JSON :
[image]

And While Importing the JSON File in Firebase , the JSON gets JUMBLED UP after the Key 9,10,100 :
[image]

How to Fix this , I have also tried importing the JSON using Firebase Import Node.js Module , but still facing this same issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not "jumbled up" order.  In fact, there is no documented order to child nodes.  What you're seeing is just how the Firebase console sorts child keys, which is [lexicograpic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order) (or, dictionary) order.  In that order, "CO-100" comes after "CO-10" (and just after "CO-09"), and that's totally expected based on the way UTF-8 strings naturally sort.

If you need a predictable sort order to child nodes when you read them back out of the database, you should sort them as you see fit in the client app that performs the query.

Comment: Thanks For the Reply Sir, so, I am getting all these Values in an Android App. I also used Collections.reverse() method, but the Data isn't displayed in an Organised Pattern . Is there I can do something to fix the Lexicographic order ? @Doug

Comment: As I said in my answer, you should sort the children in your app that queries Firestore.  Please read the article I linked on lexicographic order - it's not "reverse" order.

Comment: Okay Sir, Got it. However, any java code was way more useful . Currently Im searching how to fix this in Coding, instead of changing DB